# how to iterate array of array in javascript to get common item ?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
/*1 2 3
  2 1 3
  2 3 1 */

var arr = [

  [1,2,3],
  [2,1,3],
  [2,3,1]


]

function commonElementInColumn(arr){
  var a = arr[0],
      b=false,
      commItem =[];
  for(var i=0 ; i<a.length ;i ++){
    var item = a[i];
    for(j=1; j< arr.length ; j++){
      if(arr[j].indexOf(item) !==-1){
        b =true
      }else {
        b= false
      }
    }
    if(b){
      commItem.push(item)
    }
  }
  return commItem
}

console.log(commonElementInColumn(arr))
```

I am trying to find common `column` item in matrix .I tried like this. But not getting expected output .I am getting `[1,2,3]` but 
can we add any logic which find common element in columns

Expected output is **`[1]`**

Let take I have `m x n` matrix .I want to find common element which is present in all coloum.

See input

```
/*1 2 3
  2 1 3
  2 3 1 */
```

- `1` is present in all  three column.
- `2` is present only first and second not in `third`
- `3` is present on second and third but not in first

Comment: Didn't you ask this same question earlier today?

Comment: this is not correct anser ..expected is `1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following

```js
var arr = [
  [1,2,3], [2,1,3], [2,3,1]
];

// Create the map of items with value to be an array of indexes
var map = {};
var result = [];

// iterate over the array
arr.forEach(function(subArray){
  subArray.forEach(function(item, index){
    map[item] = map[item] ? map[item] : [];
    // if the map has the item and the index already exists in the array, skip
    if(!map[item].includes(index)) {
      map[item].push(index);
    }
    // if the length is same as the array item length (assuming same for all subArray's) then it means all indexes have been covered
    if(map[item].length === arr[0].length) {
      result.push(item);
    }
  });
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different approach with a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) for the values and a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) for each value for collecting the indices. Later check the size of the sets and take the keys of the map as result arrray.

```js
function commonCol(array) {
    var map = new Map;
    array.forEach(a => a.forEach((v, i) => {
        if (!map.has(v)) {
            map.set(v, new Set);
        }
        map.get(v).add(i);
    }));

    return Array
        .from(map.entries())
        .filter(({ 1: v }) => v.size === array[0].length)
        .map(([k]) => k);
}

var array = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 1, 3], [2, 3, 1]];

console.log(commonCol(array));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Array#filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) on first subarray since it must contain any common values.

Within that filter use a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to pass all indices for each number to. Since a Set must have unique values you can then check it's `size` and if it matches subarray length then all indices are unique

```js
var arr = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [2, 1, 3],
  [2, 3, 1]
]

function commonElementInColumn(arr) {  
  // return filtered results from first subarray since it has to contain any common values `
  return arr[0].filter((num) => {
    // get all indices for this number as array
    let indices = arr.map(subArr => subArr.indexOf(num));
    //create a set from this array which will void duplicates
    let uniqueIndices = new Set(indices);
    // if size of set is same as subarray length then all indices for this number are unique
    return uniqueIndices.size === arr[0].length;
  });

}

console.log(commonElementInColumn(arr))
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at that:

```js
var arr = [
  [1,2,3],
  [2,1,3],
  [2,3,1]
]

// Creates another array from arr organized by column
var byColumn = arr.reduce((accumulator, item) => {
  item.forEach((element, index) => {
    if(!accumulator[index]) accumulator[index] = [];
    accumulator[index].push(element);
  });
  return accumulator;
}, [])

// Gets the first array of arr to iterate
var firstArray = arr[0];

// Gets an array of elements that appears in all columns
var filteredNumbers = firstArray.filter(element => {
  return byColumn.every(item => item.includes(element));
});

console.log(filteredNumbers); // [1]
```